# How can you change the default ContentType in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest, servicestack

I have [registered a new content type](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/vcard-format.htm) in ServiceStack with:

```
appHost.ContentTypeFilters.Register("application/x-my-content-type", 
   SerializeToStream, DeserializeFromStream);
```

And everything works as expected, if the client sends the content type in the http stream.

Unfortunately, I have a client that is not in my control of HTTP Request Heads and does not send the content type.

How can I get ServiceStack to set the default content type for that route?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On every ServiceStack [/metadata page](http://mono.servicestack.net/json/metadata?op=Hello) lists the different ways a client can request a specific Content-Type:

> To override the Content-type in your clients HTTP **Accept** Header, append **?format=xml** or add .**format** extension

E.g. The client can specify your custom ContentType with **?format=x-my-content-type**, adding `.x-my-content-type` extension or by  specifying the HTTP Header (in the HttpClient):

> Accept: application/x-my-content-type

Otherwise if your HttpClient doesn't send an Accept header you can specify the default content type in your AppHost with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
     DefaultContentType = "application/x-my-content-type"
});
```

*Note: All Configuration options in ServiceStack are set on `HostConfig`.*

The issue when calling web services from a web browser is that they typically ask for `Accept: text/html` which by contract ServiceStack obliges by returning back HTML if it is enabled.

To ensure your Content-Type is always returned you may also want to disable the HTML feature with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Html),
});
```

Otherwise if you want to **override the Accept** header you can force your service to always return your Content-Type by decorating your Response DTO inside a HttpResult, i.e:

```
return new HttpResult(dto, "application/x-my-content-type");
```

Otherwise anywhere outside of your Service (e.g. Request/Response filter) you can set the Response ContentType anywhere that has access to a `IHttpRequest` with:

```
httpReq.ResponseContentType = "application/x-my-content-type";
```