# ServiceStack - dictionary to csv

Tags: c#, csv, dictionary, servicestack

In my project I use ServiceStack to allow user to export data in csv format. It's ServiceStack that makes the job but it always sorts my dictionary by alphabetical and I don't want that. I want that my csv file have his columns in exact order that I inserted my data in the dictionary.

There is a way to configure ServiceStack to don't make this sort ?

My dictionary :

```
var excelResult = new Dictionary<string, string>();            

                    excelResult["Id"] = x.Id.ToString();
                    excelResult["IBS Account Id"] = x.IBSAccountId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    excelResult["IBS Order Id"] = x.IBSOrderId.ToString();
```

And in my csv file, instead of "Id, IBS Account Id,IBS Order Id" I have "IBS Account Id,IBS Order Id,Id"

Thank you very much !!

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to custom or override CSV serializer of ServiceStack. If you have any idea about that. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I discover it's impossible(?) to override or custom ServiceStack CsvSerializer.

So, my solution (because I have to do something after all) : Create a new custom type, serialize it and write it in a csv file :)

Step 1 : (AppHOst.cs) Register my new type "tapas" (because I like tapas but I don't think my lead will be ok with that :p)

```
ContentTypeFilters.Register("text/x-tapas",
TapasSerializer.SerializeToStream, TapasSerializer.DeserializeFromStream);
```

Step 2 : (AppHOst.cs) Configure the response for the creation of the file

```
ResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
        {
            if (req.ResponseContentType == "text/x-tapas")
            {
                res.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition,
                    string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.csv", req.OperationName));
            }
        });
```

Step 3 : (myPage.handlebars) Swap csv with my new type in my request link (in java for my project)

```
<li><a href="../url/orders?format=x-tapas" target="_blank">{{localize "ExportOrders"}}</a></li>
```

Step 4 : Your Tapas Serializer !

```
public class TapasSerializer
{
    static TapasSerializer()
    {
    }

    public static void SerializeToStream(IRequestContext requestContext, object response, Stream stream)
    {
       //TO DO
    }


    public static object DeserializeFromStream(Type type, Stream stream)
    {
        //TO DO
    }

}
```

Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to unregister the default 'text/csv' content-type and serializer.

In AppHost.cs,

```
using ServiceStack.Common;
```

In AppHost Configure()...

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
{
    EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Csv),
});
```

Your apphost will no longer do any special handling for text/csv. At that point, you should be able to register it again as you wish, as explained in [How to register your own custom format with ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/ServiceStack-CSV-Format#wiki-how-to-register-your-own-custom-format-with-servicestack).

Substitute your TapasSerializer for CsvSerializer and you should be good.

I discovered a clue how to do it from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326810/how-can-you-change-the-default-contenttype-in-servicestack).